# Symbolizing frequency as $v$

Tags: terminology, conventions, notation, frequency

In my school textbook $v$ is symbolized to the frequency of the wave. Is that correct?
[image: School TextBook]

I also saw this convention used in [Chemistry: The Central Science
By Theodore L. Brown, H. Eugene LeMay Jr](https://books.google.lk/books?id=zSziBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA180&ots=xMzBllYezn&dq=Waves%20are%20periodic%2C%20which%20means%20that%20the%20pattern%20of%20peaks%20and%20troughs%20repeats%20itself%20at%20regular%20intervals.%20The%20distance%20between%20two%20adjacent%20peaks%20or%20between%20two%20adjacent%20troughs%20(distance%20between%20a%20cycle)%20is%20called%20the%20wavelength%20(%EF%81%AC).%20The%20number%20of%20complete%20wavelengths%2C%20or%20cycles%2C%20that%20pass%20a%20given%20point%20each%20second%20is%20the%20frequency%20(%EF%81%AE)%20of%20the%20wave.%20Frequency%20is%20expressed%20in%20cycles%20per%20second%20using%20a%20unit%20called%20hertz%20(Hz).%20Since%20it%20is%20understood%20that%20cycles%20are%20involved%2C%20it%20may%20also%20be%20simply%20called%20%E2%80%9Cper%20second%2C%E2%80%9D%20which%20is%20denoted%20by%20s-%201%20.%20Hence%2C&pg=PA182#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image]

Comment: What is your question?  I think both say the same thing. Are you talking about a v versus a greek nu ν?  zi think the v in the first image is actually a nu.  both letters are a ν which looks like a v.  c = vf - yes thats correct.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. It's not an opinion based question, and it is an important question in physics in how we relate physical ideas to mathematical notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers are mostly correct, but an issue in your wording and thinking needs to be addressed.

Notation is never incorrect or correct by itself. As other answers say, you *usually* see the Greek letter $\nu$ to represent frequency, but you can use any variable for anything as long as you are consistent with your notation and are correct with what is physically being described by your equations. For example, I can say an object's kinetic energy $\Omega$ is $$\Omega=qvB$$ where $q=1/2$, $v$ is the object's mass, and $B$ is the square of the object's velocity$^*$. Then staying consistent with this, the momentum of the object would be $v\sqrt B$. I'm not using the usual variables, but no one can say I'm incorrect since I have defined what my variables mean and how I have used them is physically correct. However, you could say I'm incorrect if I then said momentum is $vB$. This would not be because my equation isn't the usual $p=mv$, but because based on my definitions I'm not getting an actual momentum (in usual variables I would be saying momentum is $mv^2$, which is indeed wrong because momentum is not "mass times velocity squared").

Therefore, your question "Is that correct?" is not answerable without knowing what each variable means. It looks like the sources you give are being consistent within their own work and what their variables physically represent. So yes, they are correct. But their correctness isn't because they use the usual variables, and they wouldn't be incorrect if they didn't use the usual variables.

---

$^*$ I could go even further and say $\Omega=q+v+B$ where "$+$" means to multiply. I wouldn't be wrong, but at this point I would probably be going against convention too much and start losing the attention and respect of my readers.

Comment: Can I use any symbol I like in my exams too?

Comment: @SivaManasan Haha. Technically yes. Although I can't guarantee your professors will enjoy it. I never said it's best to use any symbol you want. You just technically won't be wrong if you stay physically correct in your equations. When possible you should use the variables people are familiar with. In other words, my answer talks about what you *can* do rather than what you *should* do :)

Answer (score 4):

It should be the lowercase Greek letter [nu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nu_(letter)). Like this:

## $\nu$

whereas the italic lowercase Roman letter vee looks like this:

## $v$

In LaTeX/MathJax, write lowercase nu using `\nu`. Eg, 
$$\nu=\frac{c}{\lambda}$$ 
can be written using

```
$$\nu=\frac{c}{\lambda}$$
```

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nu_(letter)) says:

> Its Latin equivalent is N, though the lowercase resembles the Roman
>   lowercase v ($\nu$).
>
> The uppercase Nu is not used, because it is normally identical to
>   Latin N. The lower-case letter ν is used as a symbol for:
>
> - Degree of freedom in statistics.
> - **The frequency of a wave in physics and other fields; sometimes also spatial frequency; wavenumber**
> - The specific volume in thermodynamics.
> - Kinematic viscosity in fluid mechanics.
> - Poisson's ratio, the ratio of strains perpendicular with and parallel with an applied force.
> - Any of three kinds of neutrino in particle physics.
> - One of the Greeks in mathematical finance, known as "vega".
> - The number of neutrons released per fission of an atom in nuclear    physics.
> - A DNA polymerase found in higher eukaryotes and implicated    in translesion synthesis.
> - Molecular vibrational mode, νx where x is the number of the vibration (a label).
> - The stoichiometric coefficient.
> - The greatest fixed point of a function, as commonly used in    the μ-calculus.
> - Free names of a process, as used in the π-calculus.
> - The maximum conditioning possible for an unconditioned stimulus in the Rescorla-Wagner model.
> - The true anomaly, an angular parameter that defines the position of a    body moving along an orbit (see orbital elements).

Answer (score 0):

Yep it's nu. When you write it use two curved lines, not two straight lines.

[image]